# Show that there exist $T\in B(X,Y)$ such that $T^*=S$ where $T^*(\phi)=\phi\circ T$ for $\phi\in Y^*$.

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces and let $S\in B(Y^*,X^*)$ be continuous in weak$^*$ topology. Show that there exist $T\in B(X,Y)$ such that $T^*=S$ where $T^*(\phi)=\phi\circ T$ for $\phi\in Y^*$.

So what I was thinking was to take $T$ as $\phi^{-1}\circ S(\phi)$, but how do we know that $\phi^{-1}$ exists for each $\phi \in Y^*$? Thats where I stuck. Any help is appreciated.